# PHP echo on top of page

Tags: php, mysql, sql, if-statement, echo

What I'm trying to do is to echo something at the top of the page while it catches something ad the bottom.

This is my script:

```
 <html>
<head>
  <title>Westpop</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="opmaak.css">
</head>
<body>
<div id="header"><a href="Index.php"></a></div>

 <?php 

    $host = "localhost";
    $gebruikersnaam = "root";
    $wachtwoord = "";
    mysql_connect($host, $gebruikersnaam, $wachtwoord);

    $demooistedatabase = "c5g4westpopintranet";
    mysql_select_db($demooistedatabase);

    $achternaam = $_POST["achternaam"];
    $voornaam = $_POST["voornaam"];
    $gbdatum = $_POST["geboortedatum"];
    $email = $_POST["email"];
    $geslacht = $_POST["geslacht"];
    $wachtwoord = $_POST["wachtwoord"];
    $woonplaats = $_POST["woonplaats"];
    $adres = $_POST["adres"];
    $telefoonnummer = $_POST["telefoonnummer"];
    $functie = $_POST["functie"];


    $achternaam = stripslashes($achternaam);
    $voornaam = stripslashes($voornaam);
    $gbdatum = stripslashes($gbdatum);
    $email = stripslashes($email);
    $geslacht = stripslashes($geslacht);
    $wachtwoord = stripslashes($wachtwoord);
    $woonplaats = stripslashes($woonplaats);
    $adres = stripslashes($adres);
    $telefoonnummer = stripslashes($telefoonnummer);
    $functie = stripslashes($functie);


    $query ="INSERT INTO vrijwilliger (voornaam, achternaam, gbdatum, geslacht, wachtwoord, woonplaats, adres, telefoonnummer, functie, activiteitID, groepID, email)
                VALUES('$voornaam','$achternaam','$gbdatum','$geslacht','$wachtwoord','$woonplaats','$adres','$telefoonnummer','$functie',null,null,'$email')";

?>
<div id="registreer">
<center>
<br><br>
<?php

 $foutloos=true;


if(preg_match("/^.*(?=.{8,})(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).*$/", $wachtwoord) === 0)
{
echo '<fblack>Wachtwoord moet minstens 8 tekens lang zijn, een kleine letter, grote letter én cijfer bevatten.<br><fblack>';
$foutloos = false; 
}

if(preg_match("/^[0-9]{10}+$/", $telefoonnummer) === 0)
{
echo '<fblack>Het telefoonnummer moet 10 cijfers bevatten.<br><fblack>';
$foutloos = false; 
}


if(preg_match("/^[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{1,2}-[0-9]{1,2}$/", $gbdatum) === 0)
{
echo '<fblack>Geboorte datum moet op dit formaat ingevoerd worden: JJJJ-MM-DD<br><fblack>';
$foutloos = false; 
}

if(preg_match("/^[a-z0-9]+([_\\.-][a-z0-9]+)*@([a-z0-9]+([\.-][a-z0-9]+)*)+\\.[a-z]{2,}$/i", $email) === 0)
{
echo '<fblack>Email moet hier op lijken: email@provider.com<br><fblack>';
$foutloos = false; 
}


if(preg_match("/^[A-Z][a-zA-Z -]+$/", $voornaam) === 0)
{
echo '<fblack>Voornaam is niet geldig ingevoerd, heeft u een hoofdletter gebruikt?<br><fblack>';
$foutloos = false; 
}


if(preg_match("/^[A-Z][a-zA-Z -]+$/", $achternaam) === 0)
{
echo '<fblack>Achternaam is niet geldig ingevoerd, heeft u een hoofdletter gebruikt?<br><fblack>';
$foutloos = false; 
}


if ($geslacht == '') 
{
echo '<fblack>U heeft uw geslacht niet aangegeven.<br><fblack>';
$foutloos = false; 
}


if(preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z]+\ +[0-9]+$/", $adres) === 0)
{
echo '<fblack>Het adres is verkeerd ingevoerd.<br><fblack>';
$foutloos = false; 
}


if(preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z\s]+$/", $woonplaats) === 0)
{
echo '<fblack>De woonplaats is verkeerd ingevoerd.<br><fblack>';
$foutloos = false; 
}

if ($foutloos == true)
{
mysql_query($query)
or die('<fblack>U staat al in ons systeem<A HREF="javascript:javascript:history.go(-1)"><br><br>Klik hier om terug te gaan</A><fblack>');
echo "<fblack>Uw registratie is succesvol verwerkt!<br>Log <a href='login.php' MEDIA=screen>hier</a> in<fblack>";
}
else
{

echo '<fblack><br><A HREF="javascript:javascript:history.go(-1)">Klik hier om terug te gaan</A><fblack>';
}

?>
</center>
</div>
<?php
include ("html_end.php");
?>
```

Now on top of the page I want to show an error message.
So how do I echo something on the top, while it catches it in the IF?

```
if ($foutloos == true)
{
mysql_query($query)
or die('<fblack>U staat al in ons systeem<A HREF="javascript:javascript:history.go(-1)"><br><br>Klik hier om terug te gaan</A><fblack>');
echo "<fblack>Uw registratie is succesvol verwerkt!<br>Log <a href='login.php' MEDIA=screen>hier</a> in<fblack>";
}
else
{
ECHO SOMETHING THAT HAS TO GO ABOVE THE PAGE
echo '<fblack><br><A HREF="javascript:javascript:history.go(-1)">Klik hier om terug te gaan</A><fblack>';
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: MVC is your friend... you really should separate logic from view, avoiding the mix between markup and php code

Comment: Where does MVC stand for? I'm a student and I just learned the PHP and SQL basics

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model-View-Controller : is a modern pattern adopted by many framework and in several languages (e.g. in php most remarkable example are Zend Framework or Symfony).

Comment: Although MVC is definitely the way to go, it can be overwhelming for a beginner. You can start out by just seperating logic and view in one file, PHP at the top and HTML at the bottom.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to seperate your logic from your view. So put your PHP on top, then the HTML at the bottom, for example:

```
//This goes at the top, only PHP here!
$host = "localhost";
$gebruikersnaam = "root";
$wachtwoord = "";
mysql_connect($host, $gebruikersnaam, $wachtwoord);
//etc
 $query ="INSERT INTO vrijwilliger (voornaam, achternaam, gbdatum, geslacht, wachtwoord, woonplaats, adres, telefoonnummer, functie, activiteitID, groepID, email)                VALUES('$voornaam','$achternaam','$gbdatum','$geslacht','$wachtwoord','$woonplaats','$adres','$telefoonnummer','$functie',null,null,'$email')";
$foutmelding = false; //Start without error obviously, we check later if this value has been changed at all.

if(preg_match("/^[0-9]{10}+$/", $telefoonnummer) === 0) //Something is not right
{
    $foutmelding = "Je telefoon nummer klopt niet!"; //By setting this to a string it will evaluate to `true` later on, thus showing the error message.
}
//More error checking etc...
```

Then all the way down in your view, e.g. HTML;

```
<?php if($foutmelding) { ?>
   Er is een fout opgetreden; <?php echo $foutmelding; ?>
<?php } else { ?> 
   Alles is goed gegaan, dankjewel!
<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the PHP buffers. Don't send the content of the buffer until you reach the end of the php file.

http://php.net/manual/en/book.outcontrol.php

```
<?php
// Open buffer #1
ob_start();
print "Line 1\n";

// Open buffer #2
ob_start();
print "Line 2\n";

// Grab the contents of buffer #2
$buf2 = ob_get_contents();

// Close buffer #2
ob_end_clean();
print "Line 3\n";

// Grab the contents of buffer #1
$buf1 = ob_get_contents();

// Close buffer #1
ob_end_clean();

// Output the buffer contents
print $buf1;
print $buf2;
?>
```

Comment: This might not be appropriate for this answer but +1 for buffers.

Answer (score 0):

You have at least 2 ways of doing this:

- server side - start using some template engines like smarty and separate your presentation layer from the business layer as F. Calderan suggested
- client side - add some javascript code to the HTML generated by your php script. Make this execute at the end of the page and modify the DOM of the HTML.

Answer (score 0):

if you don't want to rewrite your project to mvc, here is just a quick solution..: use [ob_start](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php)